# ORACLE: wrong number or types of arguments in call to PROCEDURE

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I have a .NET Application trying to call a stored procedure like this:

```
 private void Method(Company company)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(company.Object);
            var parameters = new List<OracleParameter>
            {
                new OracleParameter("ID", OracleDbType.Int32, company.Id, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter("ACTIVITY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, json, ParameterDirection.Input)
            };
            _oracleDataAdapter.ExecuteProcedure<ObjectModel>("DB.MY_PROCEDURE", parameters);
        }
```

I have my procedure like this:

```
  PROCEDURE        MY_PROCEDURE
  (
      ID IN NUMBER,
      ACTIVITY IN VARCHAR2
  ) AS 
  BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO DB.TABLE (ID, ACTIVITY) VALUES (ID, ACTIVITY);
  END MY_PROCEDURE
```

The names of the procedure is the same, the names of the properties are the same, why I am getting this error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to DB.MY_PROCEDURE
```

I checked and copy exactly the names of the properties and the name of the Stored Procedure, I changed the names for this example purpose so that is not the error.

UPDATE
The OracleDbType Enum is from the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client nuget, And Int32 is the equivalent for "Number" on this case, here is an screenshot from the documentation (FYI I tested it with Int16, Int32, Int64, Long, Decimal, Double and it didn't work):
[image]

Comment: A number is not an Int

Comment: @nbk For the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client nuget it is, here is the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/entityDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-8EE05F96-7262-4804-A713-EAF190303DBD

Comment: yes but as you see the number has no digits in the manual your has the default, which isn't 0

Comment: @nbk I am not understanding properly, please can you explain according to you, what should I use on the OracleDbType  enum?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm#ODPNT2286) suggests `OracleDbType.Decimal` is the equivalent of Oracle's `NUMBER` type

Comment: @MT0 It didn't work with Int16, Int32, Int64, Decimal, Double or Long

Comment: @MT0 does anyone of you know what could it be? I haven't figure it out

Comment: I don't know anything about tools you use. But, are you SURE that it is about the NUMBER datatype? What if it is about VARCHAR2? Could you test it with a procedure with only one parameter and *tweak* it until you make it work, and then move on to another one? One more - pretty much stupid - suggestion: if it works with VARCHAR2 datatype, set both parameters' datatypes to VARCHAR2, pass strings to procedure and either let Oracle do implicit datatype conversion, or apply TO_NUMBER to parameter which is supposed to be a number.

Comment: It's rather inefficient to solve multiple issues at a time: why not focus on a single parameter? Keep only one of them, make the code to work or ask the question about the specific issue with that parameter, then go forth and combine multiple working solutions together.

Comment: AS per this link varchar2 is supported only 4000 characters ,please check the size of your json string once https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/entityEDMmapping.html#GUID-A7A3F1A1-A630-48E4-85C9-888D4ABA1BBA